# Experience Editor - An error occurred. [Log message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source]

Tags: experience-editor, jss

I have a new `Sitecore 9 vanilla install`. I created a JSS site and entered the connected mode. Immediately I'm getting an error in the Experience Editor. On-screen I see:

```
An error occurred. [Log message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source]
```

And in the logs I see:

```
18856 17:04:35 ERROR Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
Source: System.Core
  at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
  at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Utils.ItemUtility.GetLockedItemsCount(String userName)
  at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Utils.ItemUtility.GetLockedItemsCountOfCurrentUser()
  at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.MyItems.MyItemsCountRequest.ProcessRequest()
  at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs requestArgs)
```

I checked the locked items in the control panel and nothing is locked. Not sure why this method is failing

Comment: can you check if data source items that broken links?

Comment: I dont see any obvious broken data sources, but Im wondering if its related to workflow. The JSS workflow is different...

Comment: Check all rendering associated with that page has correct data source defined and created..

Comment: Please see my above comment. I already reviewed datasources. None appear to be broken.